# UISwitch controlling

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I'm learning Obj-C and trying to build my first apps.
I wanted to do something using UISwitch.
Sadly I have problem with checking value of this element.

I got such action:

```
@synthesize SwitchValue;
[...]
- (IBAction)ToggleEnabled{
if ([SwitchValue isOn]) {
    NSLog(@"Switch ON");
    // [myImageView startAnimating];
} else {
    NSLog(@"Switch OFF");
    // [myImageView stopAnimating];
}
```

The problem is that in logs are displayed only:

```
2012-02-12 13:50:56.764 App[2763:f803] Switch OFF
2012-02-12 13:50:57.965 App[2763:f803] Switch OFF
2012-02-12 13:50:58.848 App[2763:f803] Switch OFF
```

By each setting of toggle.
I tried conditional even with "SwitchValue.on" or "SwitchValue.enabled" but didn't work as well.

Comment: have you made your connection properly and what event you are observing. value changed???

Comment: So ToggleEnabled is the action that happens when the switch is toggled, correct?

What happens if you do an `NSLog(@"%@", SwitchValue)` at the beggining of `ToggleEnabled`?

Comment: @InderKumarRathore Hm. I guess I connected it correctly with UISwitch. http://cl.ly/1d0I3i003R1z1g3R1Y1Q

Comment: @yuji Displays "(null)" in Logs

Comment: I couldn't find anything from your pic..!!1

Comment: `@interface VillageSecondViewController : UIViewController {
    IBOutlet UISwitch *SwitchValue;

}

@property(nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UISwitch *SwitchValue;

- (IBAction)ToggleEnabled;

@end`

Comment: Try to reassign your UISwitch IBOutlet. As I guess your IBAction connection is proper but your code is unable to find properties for SwitchValue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems like your `IBoutlet UISwitch *SwitchValue;` is not connected to xib file's Switch. Double check this and you can do this way:

```
- (IBAction)ToggleEnabled:(id)sender{
    UISwitch *sw = (UISwitch *)sender;
    if ([sw isOn]) {
        NSLog(@"Switch ON");

    } else {
        NSLog(@"Switch OFF");
    }
}
```

Comment: Ahh yes, I didn't connect IBOutlet to xib. Only IBAction was connected. Thanks :)